# What is an "Object" in a JavaScript NodeJS code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, syntax

I saw the following code:

```
const User = require('../model/User');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const handleRefreshToken = async (req, res) => {
    const cookies = req.cookies;
    if (!cookies?.jwt) return res.sendStatus(401);
    const refreshToken = cookies.jwt;

    const foundUser = await User.findOne({ refreshToken }).exec();
    if (!foundUser) return res.sendStatus(403); //Forbidden 
    // evaluate jwt 
    jwt.verify(
        refreshToken,
        process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
        (err, decoded) => {
            if (err || foundUser.username !== decoded.username) return res.sendStatus(403);
            const roles = Object.values(foundUser.roles);
            const accessToken = jwt.sign(
                {
                    "UserInfo": {
                        "username": decoded.username,
                        "roles": roles
                    }
                },
                process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
                { expiresIn: '10s' }
            );
            res.json({ roles, accessToken })
        }
    );
}

module.exports = { handleRefreshToken }
```

And I can not understand what is the `Object` in this line of code:

```
const roles = Object.values(foundUser.roles);
```

I mean is it instance of a class? What class? Where did it instantiated?

What does this `Object` refer to?

Comment: It's a class/type. In javascript classes are also objects/instances because everything are objects/instances. Object is the base class of all classes. Essentially any class in javascript eventually inherit from the Object class/object/constructor/type.

Comment: ... the base class of all classes (the Object type) has several static methods such as `.values()` etc. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object in Node.JS is anything that's within curly brackets, JSON basically. And if you actually read into it everything in Node.JS is actually an object, but that's off topic.

What that line of code is doing is it is finding the foundUser, and getting all of the values under the 'roles' category, so I would assume it would be sending back all of the roles the found user has.

if you want to research more, or if I wasn't clear enough check out this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: Curly braces indicate an object literal. Functions and arrays are objects. It has nothing to do with JSON. JSON is a string format.